# SpecFlow - passing parameter(s) into a hook

Tags: specflow

In SpecFlow, is it possible to pass parameters into a hook?

For example, I would like to pass parameters for specifying the Authenticated user and setting up test base data. Something like this would ideal:

```
@AuthenticatedAs('Persona A')
@BaseData('KnowledgeBase','TicketHistory')
Scenario: a premium customer raises a support ticket within their credit limit
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use parameterized methods for hooks - SpecFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63065202/how-to-use-parameterized-methods-for-hooks-specflow). The accepted answer there provides the solution of passing data to the hooks using the context instead of parameters, which is what I was going to suggest as an answer here. See also the valuable [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63065202/how-to-use-parameterized-methods-for-hooks-specflow#comment111529682_63065761) under that answer.

Comment: Other related questions: [Is it possible to use variables in beforeFeature Hook as part of the Specflow scenario statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43755451/is-it-possible-to-use-variables-in-beforefeature-hook-as-part-of-the-specflow-sc), [Passing values to Specflow Scenario methods from feature file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59876532/passing-values-to-specflow-scenario-methods-from-feature-file), [Pass parameter to Specflow BeforeScenario method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67686272/pass-parameter-to-specflow-beforescenario-method)

Comment: I think the desire is to pass parameters to hooks that are stored as tags on the scenario, is that correct?